# $f$ is continuous and satisfies the equality given for all $0 \leq x $

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

How can i compute  $f (2)$ if $f$ is continuous and satisfies the equality given for all $0 \leq x $ :

$\int_{0}^{f(x)} t^2  dt = x^2(1-x)$ and  $\int_{0}^{x^2(1-x)} f(t)  dt = x$

Some help for this problem i´m confused this equalities and solving this, ty for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the first condition, with $x=2,$ you have

$$2^2(1-2)=\int_0^{f(2)} t^2 dt=\frac{(f(2))^3}{3},$$ that is, $(f(2))^3=-12.$ So $f(2)=\sqrt[3]{-12}.$

To deal with the second condition consider $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt.$ Then $F(x^2(1-x))=\int_0^{x^2(1-x)}f(t)dt=x.$ Taking derivatives, you get $1=f(x^2(1-x))(-3x^2+2x).$ Thus, $\displaystyle f(x^2(1-x))=\frac{1}{-3x^2+2x}.$ Solving the equation $x^2(1-x)=2$ (which doesn't have integer solutions) you get the answer.